# Right Click Functionality of a JPanel in an Applet doesn't work in a Firefox using MAC

Tags: java, swing, firefox, applet

I'm currently fixing a functionality using Firefox regarding the use of right click options.

Basically it works on the stand-alone desktop application, but it doesn't work on MAC using firefox as a browser. Other Components such as JFieldTextField's Right Click Functionality works.

My hunch would be the JPanel itself, since other components has the right-click functionality as expected.

Comment: *"My hunch .."* Prefer info. to hunches. Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: Are you talking about the applet's top level JFrame? That might be the browser's and it might catch events there. Might consider putting another component full-size inbetween...

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, Stefan. Already found the issue, it seems that e.isPopupTrigger() is not enough for right click to be read in MAC using the Firefox Browser. I used this, " SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)"